# How to find which type a exchange Body in camel is?

Tags: java, apache-camel

I create a processor to download some files from an external source.

I do it, like this:

```
CamelContext context = exchange.getContext();
ProducerTemplate template=context.createProducerTemplate();
Object answer=null;
try {
    answer=template.requestBodyAndHeaders(
        uri,
        "",
        headers);
} catch (Exception e) {
    ....
} finally {
    template.stop();
}

if (answer != null) {
    /* Here I need to know, if it is a file, or an error-message */
}
```

The problem is, the request can be an error-message (String), or it is a stream (when file is found).

How can I check this?

Thank you for any help

UPDATE:

Code of the Route is easy:

```
from("http://domain.de/getDoc?Id=123")
to("file:docs")
```

Comment: Why not signal an error situation with an exception?

Comment: Yes, I want throw an exception. But I must know if it is an error Message. If it is a file, i don't want to throw an exception.

Comment: What I meant is that you should throw an exception at the target side of the producer template. The location you are calling. Instead of returning an error message, throw an exception there. Then in the piece of code you quoted in your question check `if (answer.getException() != null)` and do your error handling there.

Comment: Sorry, Ok, but the target is a Website. And there I cannot change the return. It don't give me a 404 or other status code different 200.

Comment: If you call an HTTP server, then the response is always an `InputStream`. It is not either a string or a stream. The stream will yield the server response. Which might be the error string you are looking for. Does the server set the `Content-Type` header properly? If yes, you can use that to make decisions on how to process the response.

Comment: Show the code for the route.

Comment: See my Update. It is very Easy, but the Website don't replay with 404 If the Document don't exists. It Display a Webpage with an error Code. The http Status is in both cases 200.

Comment: you will have to parse the response, there is no other way since website is producing same output for error and success.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just "instanceof" checks will help?

Comment: is everytime org.apache.camel.converter.stream.CachedOutputStream

Comment: That can I do with: String answerStr = context.getTypeConverter().convertTo(String.class, answer); But there I must set the Converter Class.